# List of words with the FOOT vowel

Tags: pronunciation

Trying to compile an easy-to-memorize list of the words that use the FOOT /ʊ/ vowel for the use of someone who has trouble figuring out where to use that and where the GOOSE /u/ vowel. Only listing words with stressed /ʊ/—assuming a schwa will work just fine for unstressed /ʊ/, correct me if that’s wrong. So far I’ve got:

Everything* that ends in:
**-ush, -ull** (with an obvious mnemonic of push/pull)
**-ould** (the modal verbs)
**-ook** (except *spook*)
** meaning all of these use either /ʊ/ or an entirely different vowel, never /u/*

〈oo〉:
**good, hood, stood, wood,**
**foot, soot,**
**wool**

〈o〉:
**wolf, woman, bosom**

〈u〉:
**butch, put,**
**fulcrum, pulpit,**
**pussy, vulva,**
**sugar, pudding.**

And all kinds of derivatives like *cushion, brotherhood* etc.

Source: CMUdict.

Did I miss any reasonably frequent words, or ways to generalize? Honorable mention to foreign words like *hummus* or *boulevard* which I doubt it’s that important to anglicize perfectly, and *Worcestershire* which everybody’s expected to screw up in some way anyway.

Comment: When you say, "Everything that ends in: -ush, -ull", you may be forgetting such words as gush, hush, lush, gull, hull and lull, all of which (in UK RP) use the vowel /ʌ/

Comment: vulva is also /ʌ/ (and in at least some dialects there is a foot-goose merger. Of course you don't want' to learn those dialects, but it exists)

Comment: Is this BrE or AmE? Isn't the OO of "soot" pronounced differently from "foot" (and all other words in that category)?

Comment: wolf, butch, etc. ... the vowel is pronounced the same is British English. Chambers agrees with this. I think you need to specify AmE or BrE, and be careful about some words. BrE has different correct prononications for mant words. The ones you have listed are ok though ... I think!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian but there’s the asterisk. The list is to differentiate between FOOT and GOOSE, not other vowels

Comment: @Roman Odaisky: Your question is hard to understand. "Only listing..." is harder to understand than "I'm only listing..." And it would help if you told us whether you were interested in UK English or some other variety. (But Worcestershire: you got that right!)